# How do I archive .log files with Perl on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, perl, logging, archiving

In as simple a way as possible I am wondering if anyone knows how to archive .log files in a Windows XP directory by simply naming them with the current "localtime()" as part of the file name?   (*Do not assume there is a lock on the log file.*)  I tried all kinds of different ways of doing this but couldn't solve it... and there are no good examples on the web.

Here is what I am looking for:

```
for (all files > that 1 day old)   
  rename file  to  file.[datestamp].log
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you have enough reasons to reinvent/reimplement [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)?

Comment: Why not use 'logrotate'?  Usually provided on most linux distros or can be compiled from source if using a nix system that does not provide a package for it.

Comment: is there a binary for logrotate that will work on Windows XP?

Comment: A key problem you can be encountering is the file may be "locked" if the process has it open, preventing any rename operation from succeeding.  Unless the application supports internally log rotations, you will be required to stop the service to rotate the logs.  Also, when you say "doesn't not work", please provide details of what is actually failing in the script.

Comment: I tried adding code examples to this question but all it did was distract people from answering the question so I edited out my sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this looks so easy, I'm probably misunderstanding something. The task is to move for example "yada.log" to "yada.2011-05-04.log"? Then how about this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $dir = $ARGV[0] or die "Usage: $0 <directory>";
my $now_string = strftime "%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S", localtime;

opendir DIR, $dir or die $!;
my @files = readdir DIR;

chdir $dir or die $!;
for my $file (@files) {
    next if (-d $file);
    next unless ($file =~ /^(.*)(\.log)$/i);
    my $dst = $1 . "." . $now_string . $2;
    move ($file, $dst) or die "Failed to move $file: $!";
}
```

Comment: Your script works for me but it doesn't need to archive files that had been already archived.  I didn't say that in my question, but that is what I meant.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought of that a while ago.. `next if ($file =~ /20\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{6}\.log$/i);` should do it (for the coming 89 years). With this datestamp anyway.. I didn't make it very pretty, I'm afraid, only functional.

Answer (score 0):

```
opendir(FILES, '*logdir*');
my @files = readdir FILES;
closedir(FILES);
foreach(@files){
    system "move $_ $_.".localtime().".log" if -A $_ > *age*;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ultimately did it, thanks to TLP !  This script is buggy on line #12 but it barely works.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use File::Copy; 
use POSIX qw(strftime); 

my $dir;
my $file;

if ( @ARGV = 2 ) { 
  print "Two args accepted."; 
  $dir = $ARGV[0] or die "Usage: <directory> <filename>";
  $file = $ARGV[1] or die "Usage: <directory> <filename>";
  goto runblock; 
}
else { print "Number of arguments must be 2: directory filename\n"; goto fail; }

runblock: print "Renaming $file .\n";

chdir $dir or die $!;
my $now_string = strftime "%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S", localtime; 
if (-e $file) {
  if (-A $file > 7 ) {
    my $dst = "siteAlive." . $now_string . ".log"; 
    move($file, $dst) or die "Failed to move $file: $!";
    goto endscript;
  }
} 

fail: print "Failed to rename $file . Try again.\n" ;
endscript: print "End of script.\n";
```

Comment: `if ( @ARGV = 2 )` causes a subtle error. What you want is `if ( @ARGV == 2 )`, to check the value, otherwise you assign a new value to it.

Comment: You've changed some things around: You don't keep a partial name of the original file (they're all called siteAlive), you check for older than 7 days access time instead of 1, and you run it on a single file only. I'm not sure if it is intentional. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I wanted the answer "in general" but I also wanted to use what I learned in a specific scenerio.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are some modules that can do this for you, somehting like [`Logfile::Rotate`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Logfile%3a%3aRotate) for example.